# Cpp header file containing definition

Tags: c++

I'm learning a bit of c++ and came across [a project on github](https://github.com/okdshin/PicoSHA2) that implements the SHA256 hashing algorithm. This project has all its code in a header file. This confuses me a little. According to [a c++ website](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/)(unofficial), the header file is sort of definition(interface) of which methods are available and the cpp file has the implementation of these methods.

Questions:

- Is it "correct" to do the implementation inside your header like the
  github project?

  - If so, when do you put the implementation in the header?
  - If not, does this mean that the sha256 project could be improved by splitting in a header and cpp file?

Comment: That is not "the C++ website". And yes, putting all the code in a header is very common.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167723/what-should-and-what-shouldnt-be-in-a-header-file

Comment: It's using templates: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: "cplusplus.com" sounds official, but in reality it's made by "enthusiasts" and has plenty of miscomprehensions and beginners' guesses.

Comment: @molbdnilo Noted, changed text to make it clear